# Tampermonkey Script - How to prevent infinite submitting

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm trying to automate a form filling and submitting by coding a Tampermonkey script.

Below is my script:

```html
// ==UserScript==
// @name       FBA Calculator
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match        https://sellercentral.amazon.com/fba/profitabilitycalculator/index?lang=en_US
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js

// @copyright  2012+, You

// ==/UserScript==
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#search-string").val("B017C1Q7TM");
    $("input.a-button-input[type='submit']").eq(0).click();

});
```

but when the script works, it redirects to the same url, so the script just run again at this matching url, so it keeps submitting, of course that is not what I meant to do.

Any help to fix this would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

Perform the action only if the "loading" indicator is not visible:

```
if (!$("#please-wait-loading").is(":visible")) {
    $("#search-string").val("B017C1Q7TM");
    $('#search-form input[type="submit"]').click();
}
```

Or use your own flag:

```
if (!document.body.__searching) {
    document.body.__searching = true;
    $("#search-string").val("B017C1Q7TM");
    $('#search-form input[type="submit"]').click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm, I tried your suggestion, but it seems I still can not get the issue fixed. can you take a look at my second post?

Comment: WOW! Both solutions are perfect! Thank you soooo much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks WOxxOm,that is a very inspiring answer.

Only thing is the default value of the input box is "Enter your product name, UPC, EAN, ISBN, or ASIN". So I change the code as below.

```html
// ==UserScript==
// @name       FBA Calculator Test
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match        https://sellercentral.amazon.com/fba/profitabilitycalculator/index?lang=en_US
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js

// @copyright  2012+, You

// ==/UserScript==
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($("#search-string").val() == "Enter your product name, UPC, EAN, ISBN, or ASIN") {
        $("#search-string").val("B017C1Q7TM");
        $("input.a-button-input[type='submit']").eq(0).click();
    }

});
```

But unfortunately if you try to run the code, you will find every time it submits, it still redirects to the same page, and still keep submitting :(

Any other idea to fix?

Comment: Is there `B017C1Q7TM` in the url? You can check `location.href`

Comment: I checked the url, every time is the same url: https://sellercentral.amazon.com/fba/profitabilitycalculator/index?lang=en_US

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. 
It seems the code still does not work as expected.
Could you do a test run? You will find the code does not work, still keep submitting endlessly.

Comment: The latest update just works like a charm! Can't thank you enough  :)